# How to debug TypeScript in Expo Managed React Native with WebStorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native, debugging, webstorm

I'm trying to debug a React Native Expo Managed project with Custom Dev Client. It's a TypeScript project and I want to be able to hit breakpoints when debugging.

I can't get the breakpoints to hit, I've created a new Debug Configuration, changed the bundler host and port to the IP and port of the simulator, I can't seem to find any other IP address to connect to. 127.0.0.1:19000 or 19001 which the docs are referring to is not running anything so I can't use that in host and port.

I've tried updating my tsconfig.json file with:

```
  "sourceMap": true,
  "inlineSources": true,
```

But that does not work. I can't seem to be able to get this to work, it worked once so it's clearly possible but I don't understand what's required in order to get the breakpoints to hit when running a TypeScript based React Native Expo project.

I'm using the latest version of WebStorm and "expo": "~49.0.6".

What's required in order to be able to debug a React Native Expo Managed project and hit breakpoints in WebStorm?

Comment: adding debugger; as a keyword helps to hit a breakpoint, the debugging experience is still not super smooth but to anyone seeing this, try that